# How to access listViews items? (WinJS)

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to add a context menu on a ListView in WinJS (Windows Phone 8.1 UWP). First I wanted to add it by selecting the elements and adding an EventListenter. This is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="friendsTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="templatecontainer">
        <img src="/images/default-avatar.png" />
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            <div class="itemtitle label-extralarge" data-win-bind="textContent: nickname"></div>
            <div class="label-mediummid" data-win-bind="textContent: quotation"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{
     itemDataSource: WinJS.Application.sessionState.friendslist.dataSource,
     itemTemplate: select('.friendsTemplate'),
     layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }
     }"></div>
```

This is my first approach which failed:

```
var myList = document.querySelectorAll('.templatecontainer');
for(var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        // code for context menu
    }
}
```

But myList is empty. Then I tried a different approach:

```
var myList = document.getElementById('listView');
myList.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    console.log(e.srcElement.getElementsByClassName('templatecontainer'));
});
```

I manually inspected e in the function. The data is there! The elements with the class names are there!

I have no idea what's going on. How can I create a context menu in JavaScript in my listView per item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution after hours. That way I can get the index of the item in the list and it's nickname. Those are sufficient for my cases. Thanks!

```
document.getElementById('listView').winControl.addEventListener('contextmenu', function () {
    var index = document.getElementById('listView').winControl.currentItem.index;
    var selectedItem = document.getElementById('listView').winControl.elementFromIndex(index);
    var nickname = selectedItem.getElementsByClassName('nickname')[0].innerText;
})
```